# Trying to run Angular HttpClient Jasmine test against live REST API: nothing happens

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-httpclient

I have a simple "Contacts" REST service written in .Net Core.  It works fine.

I'm trying to write an Angular 8.3 client to talk to it.

The first two things I did were:

1. Create Contact.ts and Note.ts (corresponding to the REST models)
2. Create an Angular service to communicate with the .Net Core REST API.

I *thought* maybe the best way to test the service would be to use the auto-generated unit test, `contacts.service.spec.ts`.  I do *NOT* want to use a mock service: I want to use a "live" HttpClient so my Angular "contacts" service can talk directly to the .Net Core API.

It's not working: no errors, no warnings: the test just "passes" without even trying to send an HTTP message or wait for the HTTP response.

**How can I debug my Angular service against the live REST service?**

**Can I use the `contacts.service.spec.ts` Jasmine test/Karma runner, or should I do "something else" to step through code execution?**

**models/contact.ts:**

```
export class Contact {
  ContactId?: number;
  Name: string;
  EMail: string;
  Phone1: string;
  Phone2: string;
  Address1: string;
  Address2: string;
  City: string;
  State: string;
  Zip: string; 
}
```

**models/note.ts**

```
export class Note {
  NoteId?: number;
  Text: string;
  Date: Date;
  ContactId?: number;
}
```

**services/contacts.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

import { Contact } from '../models/Contact';
import { Note } from '../models/Note';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactsService {

  myAppUrl: string;
  myApiUrl: string;
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    })
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.myAppUrl = 'http://localhost:53561/';  // environment.appUrl;
    this.myApiUrl = 'api/Contacts/';
  }

  getContacts(): Observable<Contact[]> {
    const url = this.myAppUrl + this.myApiUrl;
    return this.http.get<Contact[]>(url)
    .pipe(
      retry(1)
    );
  }
}
```

**services/contacts.service.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { ContactsService } from './contacts.service';

describe('ContactsService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
    providers: [ContactsService]
  }));

  it('should be created', () => {
    const service: ContactsService = TestBed.get(ContactsService);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should retrieve all contacts', () => {
    const contactsService: ContactsService = TestBed.get(ContactsService);
    let observable = contactsService.getContacts();
    expect(observable).toBeTruthy();
    debugger;
    observable.subscribe(data => {
      debugger;
      console.log("Done");
    },
    error => {
      debugger;
      console.error("observable error");
    });
  });
});
```

**ng test**

[image: ng test]

---

I've tried adding [done()](https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests) to my service test, and tried instantiating HttpClient inside the unit test.  It's still not making any HTTP calls to the REST server :(

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ContactsService } from './contacts.service';

describe('ContactsService', () => {
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let service: ContactsService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [ContactsService, HttpClient]
    });
    // ERROR:
    //   "Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
    // Tried changing to 20000 - still getting Timeout...
    let originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 20000; // Getting timeout @default 5000
    httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
    //service = TestBed.get(ContactsService);
    service = new ContactsService(httpClient);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should retrieve all contacts', (done: DoneFn) => {
      service.getContacts().subscribe(data => {
        done();
    });
  });
});
```

**Current error (despite manually updating timeout value inside of test)**

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within 20000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within 20000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
    at <Jasmine>
```

---

Thanks to both Pytth and wessam yaacob. Here's how I got it working:

1. **Configure CORS on the .Net Core REST service**

   ```
    public class Startup
      ...
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        ...
        services.AddCors(options => {
          options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader());
        });
      ...
      public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        ...
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
   ```

I was already doing thing - but it's useful to note here

2. **Use HttpClientModule and HttpClient instead of HttpClientTestingModule and HttpTestingController**

   I never *WANTED* to use "HttpClientTestingModule", because I wanted to talk to the live service - not make a mocked call.

   I changed my code substantially along the way, but here's the unit test I finally wound up with:

   ```
    import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
    import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

    import { BlogPostService } from './blog-post.service';

    describe('BlogPostService', () => {
      let httpClient: HttpClient;
      let service: BlogPostService;

      beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [HttpClientModule],
        });
        httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
        service = TestBed.get(BlogPostService);
      });

      it('should be created', () => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
      });

      it('should retrieve blog posts', (done: DoneFn) => {
        service.getBlogPosts().subscribe(data => {
          done();
        });
      });
    });
   ```
3. **Final Note:**

CORS does *NOT* seem to work *UNLESS* I used HTTPS:

```
    export class BlogPostService {
      ...
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
          this.myAppUrl = 'https://localhost:44330/'  // CORS error if 'http://localhost:44330/'
          this.myApiUrl = 'api/BlogPosts/';
          ...
```

PS: I know all about the "academic distinction" between "unit tests" and "integration tests".  I was merely hoping the Angular "unit test" framework would give me the same convenience I have using `static void main (String[] args)` code in the Java world.

It turns out that's very definitely *NOT* the case...

I haven't tried an e2e test for this scenario yet - it was easier to just create a dummy page (a simple component) and use that for testing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to test your service against your real rest api so you have to replace `HttpClientTestingModule` with `HttpClientModule`

`HttpClientTestingModule` is just only used for mocking

aslo in your setup file , you have to add the test domain url in the accepted origin to avoid ->> CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

> in your case http://localhost:9876

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        { 
              ......
              app.UseCors(options =>
              options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:9876") 
              ......
        }
```

Comment: Excellent advice - thank you!  I'll let you know if it works!

Comment: BINGO - it worked!  Thank you!  NOTE: One additional thing I discovered was that CORS doesn't seem to work with .Net Core 3.x unless you use `https`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `done` that is provided by jasmine. Will edit to update:

https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/asynchronous/#_jasmines_code_done_code_function

---

For your update: this should move you in the right direction

```js
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

describe('LoginRepository', () => {
  let httpClient: HttpClient;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]
    });
    service = TestBed.get(LoginRepository);
    httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
  });

    describe('#login', () => {
        it('makes http request', () => {
         spyOn(httpClient, 'post');
      //...
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried to add "done()" ... but now I'm getting `NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[HttpClient]:...`.  Please see my updates above.

Comment: Looks like an issue where you aren't bootstrapping something properly. Check and make sure you are properly importing HttpClient in whatever module is under test. Please see my update. But this is almost certainly a configuration issue.

Comment: Yes, I got past the "bootstrapping" problem.  Now I'm facing an "async timeout" problem.  You updated your post before I had a chance to update mine - I'm going to try your suggestion now.  Thank you :)

Comment: Still no-go.  Every blog I've found on the web talks about how to mock up the REST call.  I don't *WANT* to "mock" it - I want to *INVOKE* it.  Perhaps that just isn't feasible from a Jasmine unit test.  I think the next thing I'm going to try is to create a dummy component with a pushbutton: and try calling the "live" service that way...

Comment: I am really curious, why do you want to actually make a call to a running server in a unit test?

Comment: Yes.  I'd like to have some Javascript that will test `contacts.service.ts` by invoking the live REST service.  Without any UI junk; without having to deal with Selenium or Protractor.  I was hoping the ".spec.ts" might be as convenient as "static void main()" in Java.  I also thought that `HttpClientTestingModule` was the "appropriate" library to use with Jasmine.  Perhaps I was wrong on all counts :(

Comment: +1 to what FoggyDay says.
To your question @Pytth, the scenario for actually running the HTTP requests could be to check whether the code build theHTTP calls correctly. Such tests could run periodically and detect broken API calls. Many times I have seen 3rd party API that neglect backwards compatibility and change their APIs without proper notice. You could see a possible solution in my response below.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to instantiate a live `HttpClient` in a test setting by providing a custom `HttpHandler`.

```js
import { XhrFactory } from "@angular/common"; // not the deprecated on in @angular/common/http
import { HttpClient, HttpXhrBackend } from '@angular/common/http';


class BrowserXhr implements XhrFactory {
    build(): any {
        return <any>(new XMLHttpRequest());
    }
}

let httpClient: HttpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpXhrBackend(new BrowserXhr()));
// now pass the HttpClient to some service
```